# How do you escape a single backslash in a JavaScript regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am creating a binary calculator and I would like to create a regular expression to match the operands and a single operator. The regular expression that I've created works correctly for everything except the backslash `\` character. Here is my regular expression:

```
re = /^([10]+)([\+\-\*\\]{1})([10]+)/;
re.test('11001+1000');
// true
re.test('11001-1000');
// true
re.test('11001*1000');
// true
re.test('11001\1000'); // I WOULD THINK THIS WOULD WORK
// false
re.test('11001\\1000'); // I WOULD THINK THIS WOULD FAIL
// true
re.test('11001++1000');
// false
```

Can anyone advise me on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: your regexp is ok (could be cleaned up though), the problem is with this string : `'11001\1000'`. Try logging it and you'll see.

Comment: Foiled again by those dastardly unicode escape sequences. Should I keep this question around?

Comment: Just for info, what does backslash compute?

Comment: Derp! Thanks @Toto you just fixed a bug. I was using the wrong slash to represent division.

Comment: OK, I've put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you create string in JS with `'\'` - it is treated as escape character. Therefore `'11001\\1000'` will become `'11001\1000'`, but creation of `'11001\1000'` will become `"11001@0"`.
You could try it:

```
let rr = '11001\1000';
console.log(rr);
```

Therefore `'11001\\1000'` is your case. And if you have string that already contains `'11001\1000'` - it will work.

Answer (score 0):

`re.test('11001\1000');`

Javascript does not see that string as "11001\1000" like you do. It sees it as the sequence of characters "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "\100", "0". Whenever a backslash appears in a javascript string, it is interpreted as an escape symbol combined with one or more following characters. If the following character is a digit, it reads in up to 3 characters, and treats them as a character code in octal. The character code in octal 100 converts to the @ symbol, so the end result of that string is "11001@0".

However, if the character immediately following the backslash is another backslash, it realizes that you mean a literal backslash, and so you get the following:

```
11001\\1000
becomes
1 1 0 0 1 \\ 1 0 0 0
becomes
11001\1000
```

which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Division sign is `/` not `\`

```js
re = /^[10]+[-+*\/][10]+/;
console.log(re.test('11001+1000'));
console.log(re.test('11001-1000'));
console.log(re.test('11001*1000'));
console.log(re.test('11001/1000')); 
console.log(re.test('11001\\1000'));
console.log(re.test('11001++1000'));
```